# Why aren't these img's counted in the parent div?

Tags: html, css, xhtml, overflow

The images at the bottom arent't counted in the overflow:hidden attribute in the all class. They overflow and the positioning is very difficult as the border of the all div does not follow the images down.

```
<div class="all">
    <div id="banner"><img src="images/banner1.jpg" alt="PCXD Banner"/></div>
    <div class="nav">
        ...
    </div>

    <h1 class="under"><br/><br/>Image><br/></h1>

    <table>
        ...
    </table>

        <img id="reviewI1" src="images/RL1.jpg" alt="Rocket League 1"/>
        <img id="reviewI2" src="images/RL2.jpg" alt="Rocket League 2"/>
        <a href="http://store.steampowered.com/app/252950/"><img id="steam2" src="images/steam.png" alt="Steam"/></a>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.all{
width:1200px;
margin:auto;
border:5px solid #404040;
overflow:hidden;
}

#reviewI1 {
width:500px;
position:absolute;
top:415px;
left:1010px;
border: 3px solid #fedd58;
}

#reviewI2 {
width:500px;
position:absolute;
top:710px;
left:1010px;
border: 3px solid #fedd58;
}

#steam2 {
width:100px;
left:1210px;
position:absolute;
top:1010px;
}
```

Comment: Where's your css ?

Comment: @Alexis sorry, added

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a height to the .all class e.g. height: 400px;

Answer (score 0):

Yours images are in `absolute` position, that mean they are **out of the DOM flow.** 
So the `overflow` property won't apply in that case. You need to remove absolute position to use it :

```
#reviewI1 {
  width:500px;
  top:415px;
  border: 3px solid #fedd58;
}
```

[See this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/d9od8e0r/2/)

Answer (score 0):

Remove the "position:absolute" from the images' styling.